# Installing Cordova plugin to meteor project using a github tarball link

Tags: meteor, github

I'm trying to install a package to my meteor project using a repository in github.
The only way Meteor allow me to install it is using a **"tarball"** specific link like this:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tarball/d8b0f6935a7c6e586188bf85f9da88a1c160790b

Although, the package version referenced in the link is not the one I need (I got that link from an old support post).

Could someone explain me how to obtain that type of link (tarball) from this repository and version (0.12.0)?
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/releases/tag/v0.12.0

So far I have tried:

1. Copy the tar.gz download link of the right version and running:
   `meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@https://github.com/aogilvie/phonegap-facebook-plugin/archive/0.6.0.tar.gz`

   > Result: "Meteor requires either an exact version, a Git URL with a SHA
   >   reference"
2. Installing it using the version number:
   `meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.12.0`

   > Result: I got "Package installed" but when `run ios-device` I got the error:
   >   "Failed to fetch plugin com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.12.0 via registry".
3. Downloading the zip file, unzip and put folder in packages folder.

   > Result: Is not working because is not a package.js inside the folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually trying to add a Cordova plugin (`meteor add cordova:...`), not a Meteor package.

Therefore, your trial 3 (local package / plugin) needs a similar `meteor add cordova:your-plugin-name@file://packages/folder-to-local-cordova-plugin` instead of a `meteor add package-name` (which will look for a `package.js` file).

Trial 2 (version number) works only for published plugins.

You should stick with your trial 1 but you have to specify the commit hash (git endpoint + `#` + commit hash) instead of the tarball link:

```
meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git#c0f8da97a1d65397ada73e958dafed3aeef2e491
```

See [Meteor Guide > Build > Mobile > Native features with Cordova plugins > Installing plugins](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-plugins) > Installing a plugin from Git

Comment: Thank you for a functional and well explained answer @ghybs, it is working now!  The way to find the commit hash is going to the URL of the github package and then look into releases > commit ID (Something like this:  -o- c0f8da9)  > and in the upper right corner you will find the commit SHA hash.  Just as an exercise I tried to generate the SHA hash by myself using some keys like the commit ID but I can't find the right key to got it.