# Whenever I add a new cordova package to Meteor I get "Error: Variable(s) missing: REVERSED_CLIENT_ID"

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, meteor, mobile-config

Building an ios application from an existing Meteor package. I have been running the following in order to get the application to become an `Xcode` project:

```
meteor build ../example-output --mobile-settings settings-staging.json --server https://example-staging.meteorapp.com:443
```

I already have a `mobile-config.js`, which includes all the [typical configurations for meteor](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html) such as `App.info`, `App.icons`, `App.launchScreens`, `App.appendToConfig`. In addition, I have the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` included in the file. Everything works fine, until I add any cordova plugins (`meteor add plugin cordova:` [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964795/installing-cordova-plugin-to-meteor-project-using-a-github-tarball-link).)

```
App.configurePlugin("cordova-plugin-googleplus", {
  REVERSED_CLIENT_ID: "com.googleusercontent.apps.010101010-bexamples123"
});
```

The application builds into a `.xcworkspace` but then has issues which I think these cordova plugins will fix. How can I configure/fix the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID and/or config issues and add cordova plugins so that this project can compile to an Xcode `.xcworkspace`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this Github post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8998), which pointed out that

> "This problem exists since 1.2.x. It sometimes happens if a Cordova
> package references another Cordova package as a dependency. I had this
> problems a lot with the cordova-plugin-compat package which is
> referenced by some others."

The solution ended up being to simply remove the cordova build:

```
rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build
```

I also removed and added the iOS platform again for good measure:

```
meteor remove-platform ios                 
meteor add-platform ios
```